# R program from Wikipedia doesn't plot

Tags: r, plot, wikipedia

I want to use a R script which is publicly available from Wikipedia: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Correlation_examples2.svg .

This program is supposed to output an image but for some reason when I paste the code to Rstudio it doesn't plot.

What can I do to make it output the image?

Comment: From the looks of the graph, it seems it would be extremely heavy and slow to make. Are you sure it doesn't plot or does it just take a reeaaly long time to do it?

Comment: Have you executed `output()` after sourcing that script?

Comment: Thanks guys. The problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two main reasons:
The script by itself doesn't plot anything. It just sets up the function that will generate the image. So pasting the code by itself won't help and you need to call the 'output' function.

However the function by itself doesn't plot anything either. It saves the plot as Rplots.svg which contains the .svg code to plot the images.
To display the plot in RStudio, use for example the [magick](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/index.html) package.

```
output() 
magick::image_read_svg('Rplots.svg')
```

Alternatively you can open the Rplots.svg file with a browser of your choice.